# Java - Android Studio MP3 Usage

Tags: java, android, mp3

I'm developing a method, in android, to call various mp3 file names instead of using countless switch cases. If there are 500+ mp3 files associated with a different name (sound) to be made, what is a better way to go about this instead of calling countless switch cases?

I use a 2d string:string array to have a pair 1:1 string match. I tried looking into mapping but using the array seemed good for having a unique index with the two strings.

I'm wanting to tie this into mp3 audio based on the string identified.

Thanks for reading !

Some things I tried

mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.array[][]);

Where beforehand I'd have a function to identify which string in array it's looking at and call the respective audio file with same name, but that might have problems in the future with duplicate strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question, but I'm assuming that you have a list of file paths leading to MP3 files and for each of these file paths you have a string identifier.

I'm also assuming that you're using [MediaPlayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) and [Media](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media(java.lang.String)).

#### Example:

```
FILE_PATH                IDENTIFIER
"C:\path\to\file.mp3"    "Jinglebells"
"C:\path\to\file2.mp3"   "Winter Wonderland"
```

---

If the above assumptions are true, then you could implement a HashMap containing the identifiers and the file paths (as URI's). This allows for fast lookup of the file paths based on easy-to-remember identifiers and removes the need for complex if-else or switch statements.

```
public class ExampleClass {
    private final HashMap<String, URI> identifierAssociations = new HashMap<>();

    public MediaPlayer getPlayer(final String identifier) {
        final URI fileURI = identifierAssociations.get(identifier);
        final Media media = new Media(fileURI);
        return new MediaPlayer(media);
    }
}
```

This is a start, but you will need to load in a list of all the file paths and an identifier for each to first populate the HashMap.

You could, as a very simple solution, simply parse the file name (without the extension) and use that as the identifier String.